# how to print node object in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

in drupal 7 we could use `kpr()` from devel module or php `print_r()` and `var_dump()` functions to print $node object in node.tpl file or hook preprocess node in purpose of debugging and finding a field or ..

but in drupal 8 we can't use php functions in twig and I tried `kint()` and `dump()` to print node in twig but no success. ( I've already set `debug: true` in services.yml ) ( more detail: `kint(node)` in twig file makes an infinite loop and causes memory size exhausted in browser).

so the question is how to print node object in drupal 8 using twig or hook preprocess node?

Q update v 1.0:

I have custom twig template for article: node--article.html.twig and it works fine:

```
<article>

<div>
    {{ content.body|render }} {# this works #}
</div>

<footer>
    {{ kint(node.field_custom.value) }} {# prints the custom field value without any problem #}
    {{ kint(node) }} {# this causes infinite loop and memory issue #}
    {{ content }} {# prints all content fields without any problem #}
    {{ kint(content) }} {# nothing happen or display with this! #}
    {{ kint(label) }} {# infinite like node #}
</footer>
```

Comment: with the devel kint module installed, `{{ kint() }}` in a template file works for me. See [this page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)

Comment: You would have to make sure that the "status messages" block is on the page.

Comment: @2pha I've updated my question with some examples. I checked the status message and it's active in block list to header region and header region is printed to page--article.html.twig but i don't see any relation between this and kint output. I'm confused what's could be wrong!

Comment: @2pha ksm() function prints the variable in status messages position because it uses drupal_set_message function

Answer (score 2):

I knew that the `kint()` function is not the problem because it displays custom arrays and objects that I created for test.
so problem was the node object itself. it was very big and printing it using `kint()` made memory limit issues. when I changed memory limit to -1 `memory_limit= -1` in `php.ini` file for testing , it took all 16GB ram of my system and it wasn't enough!

so I decreased the depth of `kint()` function from 7 to 4 in `modules/devel/kint/kint/config.default.php` ( `$_kintSettings['maxLevels'] = 4;` ) and `memory_limit=128M` in `php.ini`.

now every thing works,
hope it help someone.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. You can also get around the memory problems by setting the max levels kint will output. eg. `Kint::$maxLevels = 4;`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [VarDumper module](https://www.drupal.org/project/vardumper) which isn't quite so memory intensive as Kint. I find it a bit more user-friendly and better-looking!

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  vardumper($variables);
}
```

[image: Drupal VarDumper example]

Answer (score 0):

1- install Devel +  Twig VarDumper

2- in `www.example.com/admin/config/development/devel`

**enable** Display $page array

3- in `www.example.com/admin/config/development/devel`

**enable** Symfony var-dumper

4- in twig add

```
{{ dump() }} {# all #}
{{ dump(attributes) }} {# one #}
{{ dump(_charset) }} {# #}
```